# Call a Workflow from Custom menu Item using Javascript

Tags: workflow, ecb-menu

I have added a custom item in ECB menu using CSOM. Now i want to  start a sharepoint designer workflow on click of this custom menu item .Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Alas everytime you publish a Workflow it gets a new (GU)ID,

So starting by Workflow ID is a pain

You can start by **Name**  *(Note, this came from a button in a View, I deleted lines before pasting, so there might be typos)*

```
event.preventDefault();
var TR = GetAncestor(this, 'TR');
var itemID = TR.id.split(',')[1];
var wfName = 'YOUR_WORKFLOW_TITLE_GOES_HERE';
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.workflowservices.js', 'SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager',
    function () {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
            wfsManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web()),
            wfSubs = wfsManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
        ctx.load(wfSubs);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            wfsEnum = wfSubs.getEnumerator();
            while (wfsEnum.moveNext()) {
                var wfSub = wfsEnum.get_current();
                if (wfSub.get_name() === wfName) {
                    wfsManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(wfSub, itemID, new Object());
                    SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Init Workflow: ' + wfName + ' on item: ' + itemID, false);
                }
            }
        },function(e){console.error(e)});
    });
```